# javascript change div text on ready

Tags: javascript, html

how to change text with javascript on ready ? for example id div1 = YES then div2 display "You said YES

```
<div class="div1">YES</div> 
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried. Say us what exactly is 'not working'. this is not a free-homework website

Comment: not clear what did you want , can you explain what did you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote about IDs, but in your code is `class`.

```
<div id=div1>YES</div>
<div id=div2></div>

<script>   
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    if (div1.innerHTML == 'YES') {
        div2.innerHTML = 'You said YES';
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7r9cwf3s/

OR generally, if you want to put into the second one div 'You said ' and content of the first div.

```
<div id=div1>XY</div>
<div id=div2></div>

<script>   
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    div2.innerHTML = 'You said ' + div1.innerHTML; // returns 'You said XY'
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7r9cwf3s/1/

Comment: @user3600217: if you put this code at the bottom of your page, it will be on ready.

Comment: hey, can you please tell me how do you make it with a link like this div2.innerHTML = '<a href="#">You said YES</a>'; instead of div2.innerHTML = 'You said YES';

Comment: @user3600217: it works as you wrote, look: http://jsfiddle.net/7r9cwf3s/2/

Comment: ok but i need it in class not id

Comment: @user3600217: so just use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7r9cwf3s/4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  var text = $('.div1').text();
  
  if(text == "YES")
    
    $('.div2').text("You said yes");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">YES</div> 
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, if I understood correctly?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
 var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
 if(div1.innerText.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
   div2.innerHTML = 'You said YES';
 }
});
```